# Why IdentityRole id gets overriden by old name in View

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to make an Edit Form for IdentityRole. When the page is loaded I normaly receive the model with Id something like this "09e43076-c333-4145-bccb-8bc7f9db470e", but when the view is created I see that **@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)** gets an old name value instead of Id (see screenshots in the links below). Why is it happening? Thanks!

**GET: Edit**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public  ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (!isAdminUser())
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

        var role =  roleManager.FindByName(id);
        return View(role);
    }
```

**View: Edit**

```
@model Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Role";
}

<h2>Edit User Role:</h2>
@section RolesCSS {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Views/Role/style/style.css")" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="form-group">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Role", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "AddRoleForm" }))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Users)
            <div class="Label">
                <p>Edit New User Role Name:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="FormControl">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
            </div>
            <div class="FormControl">
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Edit Role"/>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

[screenshot of values received as model in the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkHpV.png)

[screenshot of the source of the rendered html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUfyb.png)

Answer (score 0):

*Despite I've found a solution I'm still interested what was wrong with the first aproach.*

I've found a workaround [here](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/12.19.php) (the content/explanation is in russian lang)
I created a class EditRoleModel as a temporary model, to avoid the issue I was having before,

```
public class EditRoleModel
{

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

that I pass as a model to View:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public  ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (!isAdminUser())
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

        var role =  roleManager.FindByName(id);
        var model = new EditRoleModel() {Id = role.Id, Name = role.Name};
        return View(model);
    }
```

then I slightly change the View to recieve model of type EditRoleModel:

```
@model WebUI.Models.EditRoleModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Role";
}

<h2>Edit User Role:</h2>
@section RolesCSS {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Views/Role/style/style.css")" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="form-group">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Role", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "AddRoleForm" }))
        {
            <div>@Model.Id</div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
            <div class="Label">
                <p>Edit New User Role Name:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="FormControl">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
            </div>
            <div class="FormControl">
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Edit Role"/>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

and finaly this is the controller where I update the IdentityRole:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(EditRoleModel model)
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (!isAdminUser())
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

        IdentityRole role = roleManager.FindByName(model.Id);
        if (role != null)
        {
            role.Name= model.Name;
            IdentityResult result = roleManager.Update(role);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something went wrong!");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```